# How to store long value as string

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to store a long value as string for various reasons so im trying to convert serverValue.TIMESTAMP to string but not able to. Can someone helpe me out?

Code I tried

```
mDatabaseReference.child("Chats").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId)
    .child("Seen").setValue(String.valueOf(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP));
```

Result

```
"{.sv=timestamp}"
```

The database is storing the value like that and i have no idea why. I just can't store it as a long value, so I need to convert it to string because while recieving all the values should be String due to some feature I have. So can someone help me in converting this long to string value?

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` has a type of `Map<String, String>`. It's not a long.

Comment: But without the string.valueOf it stores it as a long value @TheWanderer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is a so-called marker that you send to the database server. The database server then expands that into the actual timestamp. As you can see in your string version, the marker is actually a map.

There is no way to instruct the database to store the `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` value as a string. Your options are:

1. Modify the feature to deal with the actual numeric value.
2. Store the client-side timestamp as a string from your app, with `setValue(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))`
3. Write a Cloud Function that triggers on the server-side timestamp and then converts it to a string.